# Why is my django-crontab cronjob not working?

Tags: python, django, django-models, kubernetes-cronjob, django-crontab

I have a django-project with an app called app that has a file called `cron.py` with a function called `my_job().`

I want the `my_job()` function to be called every minute.

In my `django-project/django-project/settings.py` I have this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_crontab',
    ...
]

...

CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/5 * * * *', 'app.cron.my_job')
]
```

My `django-project/app/cron.py` looks like this:

```
from .models import TestModel

def my_job():
    TestModel.objects.create(number=100)
    return True
```

Of course I ran : `python3 manage.py crontab add` And the terminal printed:

```
 adding cronjob: (62dd7536ac2c985925ee33743a070a4c) -> ('*/5 * * * *', 'app.cron.my_job')
```

To be safe I run: `python3 manage.py crontab show` And the terminal prints:

```
Project/ccc_nema -> ('*/5 * * * *', 'app.cron.my_job')
```

To check if evrything works I run: `python3 manage.py crontab run someHash`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anik/Workplace/Office Project/ccc_nema v2/core/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/anik/Workplace/Office Project/ccc_nema v2/core/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/anik/Workplace/Office Project/ccc_nema v2/env_python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/anik/Workplace/Office Project/ccc_nema v2/env_python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/anik/Workplace/Office Project/ccc_nema v2/env_python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/anik/Workplace/Office Project/ccc_nema v2/env_python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/anik/Workplace/Office Project/ccc_nema v2/env_python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_crontab/management/commands/crontab.py", line 29, in handle
    Crontab().run_job(options['jobhash'])
  File "/home/anik/Workplace/Office Project/ccc_nema v2/env_python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_crontab/crontab.py", line 126, in run_job
    job = self.__get_job_by_hash(job_hash)
  File "/home/anik/Workplace/Office Project/ccc_nema v2/env_python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_crontab/crontab.py", line 171, in __get_job_by_hash
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: No job with hash someHash found. It seems the crontab is out of sync with your settings.CRONJOBS. Run "python manage.py crontab add" again to resolve this issue!
```

**The main issue: No matter how long I wait the job will not be executed automatically.**

1. What am I doing wrong?